# How do I display an OpenFileDialog selected file (txt) to a MessageBox?

Tags: c#, string

My goal is to select a file, and then when hitting the start button, it should display the txt (just for test) in a MessageBox window. I'm really new to coding.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    {
        ofd1.Filter = @"Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        ofd1.Title = @"Load combo!";
    }
    if (ofd1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string combo = ofd1.FileName;
        label1.Text = (ofd1.SafeFileName);
        MessageBox.Show(combo);
    }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    {
        ofd.Multiselect = false;
        ofd.Filter = @"Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        ofd.Title = @"Load a proxy list!";
    }
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string proxyl = ofd.FileName;
        label2.Text = (ofd.SafeFileName);
        MessageBox.Show(proxyl);
    }
}
```

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(combo);
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: You're getting the error because `combo` is a local variable to the `if` block of the  `button2_Click` method, declare the variable in the class scope, instead of in the method. To display the contents of the file, use [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Thanks! I will try fixing it, with what you wrote here.